# Any alternatives to extremely long SQL queries that use very long IN clauses?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The application I'm working on generates very long SQL statements as a result of very long `WHERE col IN (values) clauses`.

A typical query would be:

```
SELECT userId, userAge 
FROM users
WHERE userId IN (16,4127,51,13,17, ...{10,000 other userIds}..., 914)
```

This is "working" but it is also ugly as hell.

Are there any alternatives? Note that the users table has ~500k users, so the ~10k unique userIds are a non trivial filtering.

Note:

- The list of userIds that need to be queried changes all the time
- The list of userIds is not generated via SQL (it is the output of another tool)

Comment: Can you import the user id's into their own table and update it when necessary? Then join to it

Comment: You can think of ways to keep such generated user ids in a table and user that table select as subquery in the IN clause of your main query.

Comment: Table type parameters. It's also [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) that having such large `IN` clauses can be detrimental to performance and even cause the query to fail.

Comment: Will you ever run this query multiple times with the **same** set of IDs?

Comment: "changes all time time" Define "all the time". I recommend changing the "another tool" to update a table instead of some text file.

Comment: Would this not work? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-create-stage.html

Comment: Or put a predicate in this query that makes this IN list moot. In other words, the "another tool" has a "predicate" that creates the IN list. Put that code in this query or in a function that this query can use.

Comment: To clarify, the users of a webapp play with some sliders/settings that then queries a table form a SQL Server database, the result is a list of IDs for which I then have to extract some extra data from Snowflake.

Comment: So, the list changes whenever the users want to run the query with different settings (they can leave them unchanged for days, or change them 20 time in one hour)

Comment: What kind of "look better" are you looking for? There is an input from the users (list of ids), so the list of ids needs to show up somewhere. What would you like to improve?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess the queries look very strange in my logs... there is nothing "wrong", but it gives me a weird feeling.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your query would perform best if written this way:

```sql
SELECT userId, userAge 
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM otherTable t WHERE t.userId = u.userId);
```

This only requires that your whitelist of user IDs be written to `otherTable` at some point.  Note that the above query can benefit from the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON otherTable (userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lookup table, this article I wrote refers to what is called a JoinFilter; it tells Snowflake where to find the micro-partitions for your query.

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/querying-big-satellite-tables/